# Date range in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to write a query where it displays data between 01-April-2010 to lastday-april-2011.

But I don't want to hard code the year.  It should take from system date so it only displays records from this year april to next year april.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I interpreted your question as "display every date between April 1 of last year and April 30 of this year".  Others interpreted it as "display all the data in a particular table where some date column is between April 1 of last year and April 30 of this year".  Can you clarify which of the two interpretations you intended?

Answer (score 0):

```
select add_months( trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'), -12 ) 
       + interval '4' month 
       + level 
       - 1
  from dual
connect by level <= ( (trunc(sysdate,'YYYY') 
                       + interval '4' month) -
                      (add_months( trunc( sysdate, 'YYYY' ), -12 ) 
                       + interval '4' month) )
```

should work.  You could probably simplify the expression that computes the number of rows but I'd have to think for a few minutes about leap years.

Answer (score 0):

If the date column has no time component:

```
select ...
from mytable
where datecol between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),3)
                  and add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),16)-1
```

If the date column has a time component:

```
select ...
from mytable
where datecol >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),3)
and   datecol < add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this

SELECT *
FROM youtable
WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')+'0401' AND to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')+'0430'

Comment: This assumes that datecolumn is a VARCHAR2 with values like '20110401' in it.  Hopefully that is not the case.

Comment: Guess for Oracle should be changed to something like: TO_DATE('4/1/'+ to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('4/30/'+ to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),'MM/DD/YYYY')